# Gitlab Build Failed

Tags: javafx, netbeans, gitlab-ci

I'm developing an app in JavaFX in NetBeans, and in the gitlab the CI jobs always come back as failed.
Specificly:

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/build/empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: /builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 9 source files to /builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/build/classes
    [javac] /builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/src/park/Building.java:4: error: package javafx.scene.image does not exist
    [javac] import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/src/park/Building.java:5: error: package javafx.scene.image does not exist
    [javac] import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/src/park/Building.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Image image;
    [javac]             ^
    .
    .
    .
    .
     
     `and so on(21x more lines like above)`
 
BUILD FAILED
/builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1096: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/builds/szt-c-2020212/group-05/insertnamehere/nbproject/build-impl.xml:346: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
section_end:1619005922:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1619005922:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up file based variables[0;m
[0;msection_end:1619005923:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;
```

Here is the gitlab-ci-yml's content:

```
image: ubuntu:20.10

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install -yqq ant junit4 openjdk-15-jdk openjfx
  
# Build
build_game:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ant compile
    - ant jar

# Test
test_model:
  stage: test
  script:
    - >
      ant test
      -Dlibs.junit_4.classpath=/usr/share/java/junit4.jar
      -Dlibs.hamcrest.classpath=/usr/share/java/hamcrest-core.jar
```

I tried to install openjfx or jdk-8 in the yml file but nothing seems to be working.
What Did I do wrong?
Why can't it see the javafx package?